# GRANT to EXECUTE execute immediate truncate table in Oracle

Tags: oracle, truncate, sql-grant, execute-immediate

My user is owner of a simple schema in an instance of Oracle in my Job, let´s call my **USER  E**, with some resctinct privileges.
Also I have an **USER E_ETL**, to receive information of another database with **ETL** techonology.
My user **E** is the owner of some tables and a procedure **DO_TRUNCATE** (**E.DOCUMENT_TASKS** and **E.DO_TRUNCATE**), and the user **E_ETL** uses every day the procedure **E.DO_TRUNCATE** to clean all data inside my **E.DOCUMENT_TASKS** and insert the flash new information. But I´m having problems to **GRANT** user **E_ETL** to **execute immediate** the function to truncate table **E.DOCUMENT_TASKS**, the code and the error is those:

E.DOCUMENT_TASKS

```
  CREATE TABLE "E"."DOCUMENT_TASKS" 
   (    
    "DOCUMENT" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "REVISION" VARCHAR2(5 BYTE), 
    "TITLE" VARCHAR2(300 BYTE), 
    "STATUS" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), 
    "TASK" VARCHAR2(120 BYTE), 
    "ETL_DATE" TIMESTAMP (6) DEFAULT SYSDATE NOT NULL ENABLE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "E_D_01" ;
```

The E.DO_TRUNCATE procedure code is:

```
create PROCEDURE DO_TRUNCATE ( ptname in varchar2)
as
begin
execute immediate 'truncate table '||upper(ptname);
end;
```

I alread gave some grants for E_ETL user:

```
GRANT SELECT, DELETE, INDEX, INSERT, REFERENCES, UPDATE ON E.DOCUMENT_TASKS TO E_ETL;
GRANT EXECUTE ON DO_TRUNCATE TO E_ETL;
```

But I still have this error information:

```
Database driver error...
Function Name : executeDirect
SQL Stmt : call DO_TRUNCATE ('DOCUMENT_TASKS')
Oracle Fatal Error
Database driver error...
Function Name : ExecuteDirect
```

Thanks all!!!

Comment: That's not Oracle's error stack. Which tool do you use to run that code? Is there any ORA-XXXXX error?

Comment: You might try changing `call DO_TRUNCATE('DOCUMENT_TASKS')` to `BEGIN DO_TRUNCATE('DOCUMENT_TASKS'); END;`.

Comment: You may also have to add the schema qualifier onto the procedure name, e.g. `E.DO_TRUNCATE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error `Database driver error...` suggests that you might have an error connecting to the database; if so then you will need to sort that (but since you have not provided the error message then we cannot make suggestions).

Other issues could be:

1. Change `CALL` to Oracle's `BEGIN` `END` syntax:

   ```sql
   BEGIN DO_TRUNCATE ('DOCUMENT_TASKS'); END;
   ```
2. If you are not connecting as the `E` user who owns the procedure and tables then make sure you include the schema name:

   ```sql
   BEGIN E.DO_TRUNCATE ('E.DOCUMENT_TASKS'); END;
   ```

Comment: Dear [https://stackoverflow.com/users/1509264/mt0], it´s really runs with : BEGIN E.DO_TRUNCATE ('DOCUMENT_TASKS'); END; in Development database. But User ETL can´t use the schema ***E.*** before on they programming code. Do you have on more tip to grant the procedure wtihout mention ***E.*** ? Best Regards.

Comment: @Favini The ETL user could create a synonym to the procedure in the other user's schema.

Comment: Thanks @mo0, I´ll create the synonym, and ask for ETL team to proceed that way. I´ll post if they are suceed!

Comment: Thanks all, particularly to@mod0. It works!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is not Oracle error. Also it is saying about "executeDirect". Please elaborate more about the error

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).